# Django queryset added attribute not showing up in the template

Tags: django, templates

all_I'm having a hard time having an attribute that I'm adding to a QS to show up in my template.

I have a manager that looks something like this:

```
def created_by(self, _userProfile, dateGt=None, dateLt=None):

    results = self.filter(creator=_userProfile, ...) //Some QS here

    for result in results:
        result.finished = "It works!"
    for result in results:
        print result.finished
    return results
```

This prints in my console: (I have 2 events). I did the double for loop as a debug thing to make sure that after exiting the for loop the data was still there.

```
    It works!
    It works!
```

And then I'm calling the manager:

```
    events = Event.manager.created_by(some stuff here).order_by('-id')
```

And then the weird part: I'm passing the results of the line above to the template and show something like that:

```
{% for event in all_events %}
    <li><a href="{% url "edit_event" event_id=event.id %}">{{ event.title }} Finished:{{ event.finished }}</a></li>
{% empty %}
    <em>{% trans "NOTHING" %}</em>
{% endfor %}
```

And everything shows up (title, id, etc) but not the "finished" part.

Any idea where that could come from ? I trimmed the code for readability, but what I don't think that anything I removed is relevant here.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's the view (weird indentation because of stackoverflow 4 spaces thing)

```
def homepage(request):
variables = {}
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    datenow=datetime.now()
    me = request.user.get_profile()
    variables['all_events'] = Event.manager.created_by(me).order_by('-id') [:20]
context_instance = RequestContext(request)
template_name = "common/homepage.html"
return render_to_response(template_name, variables, context_instance)
```

Comment: I think you are forgetting to call `save()` method to propogate the changes to db you made in the model object: `result.finished = "it works" result.save()`

Comment: @catherine: I'm not sure to understand your answer? All the other components from this view are working, I am just adding an attribute that does not want to show up. All the rest of the manager works like a charm. Aamir, the db is not involved there and I do not wish to save the new attribute, it is just there for display purposes

Comment: @AlbanD can you show the view? What you have should work, so I suspect something in the view is causing your queryset to be re-evaluated so it is not the version you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a finished() method in the Event model and call directly event.finished in the template.

It works like that, but I still don't know why my first setup did not

Comment: LOL, that's what my answer in your question but someone down voted it so I just delete it anyway. There are few people here who don't like the answer even though it is true, they want an answer like there answer.